# Tangents circles in right triangle

Tags: geometry

Consider the circumscribed circle (T) of a right triangle ABC with legs $AB= 3$  cm and $AC= 4$ cm. Find the radius of the circle tangent to the  sides $AB$, $AC$ and to the circle $(T)$.

Comment: Is the circle tangent to $T$ also?

Comment: Yes, the circle is tangent the legs and at T.

Comment: I've edited the question, check if it is what you want to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Construction:- Add lines as indicated. Circle ABC has center O and circle MNS has center X.

Let the required radius be r.

Note that AMXN is a square with side r.

Then, CP = 0.5CA = 2 and OP = … = 1.5

OQ = PM = … = 2 – r

QX = r – 1.5

Apply Pythagoras theorem to ⊿OQX to obtain OX = F(r), a function of r.

F(r) + r = … = 2.5

The above is a quadratic in r and the roots are 2 or 0 (rejected).

Note: the coincidental simple answer makes me think that there should be a simpler method in handling this problem.

Comment: Thanks! Wonderful this solution!

Comment: @CarlosGomes You are welcome. If you accept this as a correct solution, you can click the "tick" on the top left corner of this post.